# How to prevent Chrome from caching index.html (and only index.html) locally with meta tags?

Tags: html, caching

When my server renders index.html, it injects some cache busting witchcraft there so that scripts are forced to reload if the version changes. If I do nothing, mobile Chrome wont even bother to ask if there is a new version of index.html.

If I add the following to the rendered index.html

```
<!-- never cache this locally -->
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

It does fetch `/` again but as an unwanted side effect it also caches none of the scripts even though the version number stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick.

`<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />`

As did the previous answer that was deleted, I just had disable cache on in the devtools.